# jQuery Modal is not support in IOS devices below 17 versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to open a modal in all devices with using HTML, CSS, jQuery. But the problem is that in IOS deices below version 17 model is not shown. when I click on button modal is open actually in console but in actual I can not see in IOS devices.

Any one have any solution off this problem please help me.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
               $('.get_btn').on('click', function (e) {
                    openModalSequence(1); // Start with the first step when the button is clicked
               });

               // Function to show the specific step and hide others
               function showStep(stepIndex) {
                    $('.box').hide();
                    $(`#step${stepIndex}`).show();
               }

               function openModalSequence(index) {
                    showStep(index);

                    $('.model_next').on('click', function (e) {
                         e.preventDefault();
                         openModalSequence(index + 1); // Open the next step on "Next" button click
                    });

                    $('.model_previous').on('click', function (e) {
                         e.preventDefault();
                         openModalSequence(index - 1); // Open the previous step on "Previous" button click
                    });
               }
          });
```

```css
.box {
     height: 90%;
     width: 90%;
     background-image: url(../img/getin_bg.webp);
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     gap: 120px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 5px;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 20px !important;
     position: absolute;
     top: 70%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     transition: 0.3s;
     z-index: 9999;
}

.model_logo {
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
}

.model_logo img {
     height: 70px;
     width: auto;
}

.model_text {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     gap: 20px;
     align-items: start;
     padding-left: 300px;
     padding-right: 300px;
     text-align: left;
}

.model_text .h1 {
     font-size: 30px;
}

.model_text font {
     color: var(--mdblue);
}

.model_text input {
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     border-bottom: 1px var(--light_blue) solid;
     font-size: 24px;
     background-color: transparent;
     color: var(--mdblue);
     width: 99%;
}

.model_text textarea {
     width: 100%;
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     border-bottom: 1px var(--light_blue) solid;
     background-color: transparent;
     color: var(--mdblue);
}

.model_text input ::placeholder {
     color: var(--mdblue) !important;
}

.model_next {
     border: none;
     font-size: 16px;
     margin-top: 50px;
     background-color: var(--dark_blue);
     color: white;
     padding: 10px 80px;
     border-radius: 50px;
     transition: .3s;
}

.model_next:hover {
     background-color: var(--light_blue);
}

.left_right_btn {
     margin-left: 80%;
     display: flex;
     gap: 20px;
}

.model_left {
     background-color: var(--dark_blue);
     color: var(--white);
     padding: 15px 18px;
     border-top-left-radius: 10px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
     font-size: 20px;
     cursor: pointer;
}

.model_right {
     background-color: var(--dark_blue);
     color: var(--white);
     padding: 15px 18px;
     border-top-right-radius: 10px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
     font-size: 20px;
     cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     pointer-events: none;
     left: 0px;
     background: fade(#333, 90);
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
     z-index: 1000;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: 0.3s;

     &.active {
          opacity: 1;
          pointer-events: auto;

          .box {
               top: 50%;
          }
     }

     &#success {
          h1 {
               font-size: 1.5em;
          }
     }

     .close {
          font-size: 20px;
          font-weight: 900;
          cursor: pointer;
          color: var(--mdblue);
     }
}

@media (max-width: 1300px) {
     .model_text {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          gap: 20px;
          align-items: start;
          padding-left: 100px;
          padding-right: 100px;
          text-align: left;
     }

     .box {
          gap: 100px;
     }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
     .left_right_btn {
          margin-left: 70%;
          display: flex;
          gap: 20px;
     }

     .model_left {
          font-size: 16px;
          padding: 10px 15px;
     }

     .model_right {
          font-size: 16px;
          padding: 10px 15px;
     }

     .model_text {
          width: 99%;
          padding: 0 20px;
     }

     .model_text .h1 {
          font-size: 20px;
     }

     .box {
          gap: 120px;
          z-index: 9999;

     }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal allmodal" id="example">
          <!-- Content for each step -->
          <div class="box" id="step1">
               <!-- Step 1 content -->
               <div class="model_logo">
                    <img src="img/black_logo.png" alt="">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark close allclosemodal" close-modal></i>
               </div>
               <div class="model_text">
                    <div class="h1">
                         <font>1 <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></font> What's your first name?*
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name...">
                    <button open-modal="example_2" class="model_next">Next</button>
               </div>
               <div class="left_right_btn">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left model_left" close-modal></i>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right model_right" open-modal="example_2"></i>
               </div>
               <!-- ... -->
               <button class="model_next">Next</button>
          </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('.get_btn').on('click', function (e) {
                openModalSequence(1); // Start with the first step when the button is clicked
           });

           // Function to show the specific step and hide others
           function showStep(stepIndex) {
                $('.box').hide();
                $(`#step${stepIndex}`).show();
           }

           function openModalSequence(index) {
                showStep(index);

                $('.model_next').on('click', function (e) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     openModalSequence(index + 1); // Open the next step on "Next" button click
                });

                $('.model_previous').on('click', function (e) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     openModalSequence(index - 1); // Open the previous step on "Previous" button click
                });
           }
      });
```

Comment: Please note that `openModalSequence` will add 2 additional click events every time it's called and that may lead to memory leaks and wrong behaviour.